# How can I remove the category filter from category page that do not have further any categories?

Tags: magento2, filter

I am using Porto Theme (Magento 2) for building an e-commerce website. I have some **categories** that has **sub-categories**, so when I go to that **sub-categories** page, then it is showing the category filter empty, so I want to remove the **category filter** only (not price filter) only where further **sub-categories** are not there. For example: https://www.ekaani.com/brands/ekaani-gods.html

I have tried to remove that, but when I try to edit `category_view.xml` page, then the whole sidebar disappears. What I have tried is that adding `remove=true` in the last block.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Porto. All rights reserved.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
             <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_banner" template="category/banner.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category_desc_main_column" template="category/desc_main_column.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/category/category_description" before="category.products"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="category.image" destination="content" before="category_desc_main_column"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main" remove="true">
            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="category_view_custom_block" after="-" template="Magento_Catalog::category/custom_block.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

For the mentioned page, I only want to remove the sub-categories that do not have further sub-categories.

> Update:

Here is my category_filter.phtml

```
    <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
?>
<?php if($category): ?>
<?php
    $categoryHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
    $subcategories=$category->getCategories($category->getId());
    if(count($subcategories)>0){
?>
<div class="block-category-list">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><?php echo $category->getName() ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ol class="items">
        <?php
        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
            if (!$subcategory->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
            }
        ?>
            <li class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $subcategory->getName() ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        $("#layered-filter-block").before($(".block.block-category-list"));
    });
    </script>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Category option from Layered Navigation options list in magento2

This is what I did to remove the “Category” section from my layered navigation so I wouldnt have any repeat information with the attributes I wanted in the layered navigation. go to `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer and open up view.phtml` for edit.

```
<?php  if($filter->getName() != __('Category')) {?>
                <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
                    <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php }?>
```

Comment: hi @Saniya, Could you please be more specific, as the specified path do not exist for me. I am going to app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/.....Then I am not seeing any template folder in that. Please help in this

Comment: Please go to this file path vendor\magento\module-layered-navigation\view\frontend\templates\layer\view.phtml please move this file in your theme folder and chec k it my above code

Comment: I have one folder named "Magento_LayeredNavigation"

Comment: Then I have layer folder-> templates->layer->view.phtml...is that correct?

Comment: yes please check it in your side this file is call or not

Comment: I am adding the whole code in the question with a update section

Comment: @saniya...please check the update section of my question. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: <?php  $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?> after this code you can apply condition if($_filter->getName() != "Category"){

Comment: <div data-role="collapsible" class="filter-options-item <?php if($i==0): ?>allow active<?php endif; ?>">
    <?php if($_filter->getName() != "Category"){ ?>
    <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title"><?php echo __($filter->getName()) ?></div>
    <div data-role="content" class="filter-options-content"><?php echo $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter); ?></div>
    <?php ? ?>
</div>

Comment: could u please check my code, do u mean this way?

Comment: yes  absolutely right

Comment: Hi sania, I think we have miscommunication. Actually when you open this url in the browser: https://www.ekaani.com/brands/ekaani-gods.html. Then you will see a left sidebar that contains two filters. First one for categories and second one for price. I want to remove categories from side bar as there is no further category asociated with that, but I want to leave price as it is. So that is my main concern. That code did'nt work for me. I really value your efforts and time. Thanking you.

Comment: I understand  your  requirement i sent u code so  u remove category in left side navigation.please check in your side

Comment: But that code you suggested to use did not work.

Comment: You suggested me to use a check with if condition. I have applied that. din't work for me. Anyway thank u

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Comment: ok mam. Thanks for the answer. I will apply in some time.

Comment: can you please upvote if it's help u

Comment: yes sure mam. Its necessary to keep you motivated so that you can contribute to this community

Comment: Hi sania. Please check my code in update section of the question. I don't know why that is not working. Please review once my code. Please let me know.

Comment: Even commneting them, does not create any effect: <div data-role="title" class="filter-options-title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo __($filter->getName()) ?></div>

Comment: Hi Sania, I have got the file where we could make the changes, please suggest me where to apply check on that. I am updating it in Update Section.

Comment: have you run cache flush command?

Comment: Please help in this case

Comment: yes did that, please check my update section

Comment: we have to check if there is subcategory under subcategory and apply that check before looping the subcategory

Comment: you are checking in wrong file bro

Comment: By editing this file, I can see the changes happening there

Comment: and in that file, I was not able to see any change like commenting any code or adding anything extra with concatenation

Comment: please do it your self .

Comment: it's okay. but do u think that I am wrong?